# Finding $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}\cos(t)}{t}\text{ d}t$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, laplace-transform

I know that
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{f(t)}{t}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathcal L \{ f(t) \} \text{ d}s$$

So

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}\cos(t)}{t}\text{ d}t=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathcal L \{e^{-t}\cos(t)\} \text{ d}s$$

$$=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{s+1}{(s+1)^2+1}\text{ d}s$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}(s+1)|_{0}^{\infty}$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\bigg(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}\bigg)=\frac{\pi}{8}$$

- Calculating the Laplace transform was obtained using [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=laplace%20transform%20e%5E%28-t%29*cos%28t%29).
- The integral does not converge as [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral%20e%5E-t%20cos%28t%29%2Ft%20from%200%20to%20inf) says.

---

Where did I make a mistake?
I know that this function is not continuous as the denominator goes to $0$, but that is not a reason for an integral to fail to converge.

---

Your help would be appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: As $t \to 0$ the integrand is $\frac{1}{t} + R(t)$, where $R(t) \in O(1)$, so any improper integral $\int_0^a \frac{e^{-t} \cos t}{t} \,dt$, $a > 0$, diverges because $\int_0^a \frac{dt}{t}$ does.

Comment: $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{s+1}{(s+1)^2+1}\text{ d}s\sim\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{s}{(s+1)^2+1}\text{ d}s=\infty$$

Comment: @TravisWillse I did not get you actually. For example, $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(\alpha x)-\cos(\beta x)}{x}\text{ d}x$ converges.

Comment: @Svyatoslav Why would we do that and what is exactly my mistake?

Comment: $\displaystyle \int \frac{s + 1}{(s+1)^2 + 1} \ \mathrm{d}s = \frac{1}{2} \ln((s+1)^2 + 1) \neq \arctan(s+1)$.

Comment: Yes, but I don't see why that comparison is relevant here: $f(x) := \frac{\cos \alpha x - \cos \beta x}{x} \in O(x^2)$, so $\lim_{a \searrow 0} \int_a^b f(x) \,dx$ is bounded for finite $b > 0$.

Comment: @sudeep5221 You are right! Thank you.